# How to launch the google maps app from another app?

Tags: java, android

How can one launch google maps app from another app with no action specified , like there are answers but all of one them specify the action to do, but if we just want to launch and let the user decide what he wants to do, how can we implement that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating an intent like this

```kotlin
// Create a Uri from an intent string. Use the result to create an Intent.
val gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.streetview:cbll=46.414382,10.013988")

// Create an Intent from gmmIntentUri. Set the action to ACTION_VIEW
val mapIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri)
// Make the Intent explicit by setting the Google Maps package
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps")

// Attempt to start an activity that can handle the Intent
startActivity(mapIntent)
```

You can check google maps intents through the official documentation here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#kotlin

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.